# How do I actualize in real time the signal strength of three WiFi Access Points?

Tags: android, wifi

I'm having some trouble to get the RSSI measurements in real time without being connected to an specific Network, i.e., I'm using wifiManager.getScanResults(); to see the RSSI values of each reachable AP, but I don't have a clue on how to do it using ScanResults! Is there any other way to perform a RSSI measurement and update him? I can't see how to do it using `WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION` in a broadcast receiver, since this method will only give me the update on the RSSI if i'm connected to a specific network, isn't it?

Basically, I want to update 3 AP's RSSI at the same time, something like this:

UPDATE_RSSI <- AP1
UPDATE_RSSI <- AP2
UPDATE_RSSI <- AP3

Answer (score 0):

I've tried doing a little with Wifi in the past, but I'm not sure if this info will be completely helpful to your exact need.

This little bit is registering the receiver and you can say wifiManager.startScan() to initiate a scan:

> ```
> IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
> registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, filter);
> wifiManager.startScan();
> ```

Then in the global scope of your activity you'll need to declare the receiver wifiReceiver

> ```
> private final BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
> {
>   @Override
>   public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
>   {
>       List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
>           ....
>    }
> }
> ```

ScanResult contains a few bits of information like [level](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#level) which is what I think you're trying to measure.

Does this information help?